# Find index of clicked textview

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I am making a gridlayout which contains multiple textviews. The xml code for the same is:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</GridLayout>
```

As you can see in this, for each of the textviews I have defined the onClick method. The click is handled like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v instanceof TextView && isInitiatePhase) {
        ((TextView) v).setText(String.valueOf(++count));
        if (count == 5) {
            isInitiatePhase = false;
        }
    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
        // now we have to start cutting/setting the color to red
        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }
}
```

The initiation is handled fine, now after the initiation phase when I am clicking the `TextViews` I want to know which one is clicked. Is there a way to find something like an index of the TextView in the `onClick()` method?

Does `LinearLayout` provide that functionality, if the `TextView` does not?

Also, is my approach correct here? Or is there another Layout that I should use for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead on adding `onClick`, we can add `onClickListener` in each child view inside linearlayout of gridlayout. Something like this,

```
//Add gridlayout id in xml
GridLayout girdLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridlayout_id);
final LinearLayout ll = gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.row1);
int childCount = ll.getChildCount();
for (final int i= 0; i < childCount; i++){
    TextView textView = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(i);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            // Do your job, i current index of child
        }
    });
}
```